# Issue grabbing all emails from DOM string with match and regex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to extract all emails from a DOM html string using regex and javascript match but I'm getting null, is it because of my regex or the string I'm using to test it?

```
var bodyHTML = '<header><div><a href="mailto:mymail@gmail.com"></a></div></header><a href="mailto:othermail@hotmail.com"></a>';

        var emailRegex = new RegExp("/([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/i", "g");
        var results = bodyHTML.match(emailRegex); 
        console.log(results);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using the `RegExp` constructor rather than a regex literal, the forward slashes and `i` at the end are getting interpreted as characters to match, and the backslashes are getting "eaten" by JavaScript's string escaping. Here's a simplified example:

```js
const regexFromConstructor = new RegExp("/a\s+/i")
// evaluates to /\/s+\//i (matches 1 forward slash, 1 "a", 1+ "s"es, another forward slash, and finally 1 "i")

const regexFromLiteral = /a\s+/i
// matches 1 "a" followed by 1 or more whitespace characters, case insensitive
```

You can solve this by using a regex literal (delimited by forward slashes) instead:

```js
const emailRegex = /([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/gi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine, you just need to construct the RegExp as a RegExp literal, that is, without quotes around it `"`:

```js
var bodyHTML = '<header><div><a href="mailto:mymail@gmail.com"></a></div></header><a href="mailto:othermail@hotmail.com"></a>';

var emailRegex = new RegExp(/([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/i, "g");
var results = bodyHTML.match(emailRegex);

console.log(results);
```